# How to return unevaluated variable?

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation

I'm not sure if this problem has been asked before as I don't know the keyword to search for it. 
I have a function where return result contains variable `b` (just for illustration).

```
myfunction[a_] := Module[{},
  1 + (2 a - 1) b ]
```

I want it to always return an expression with `b` unevaluated and only evaluate it when I do some replacement.

[image]

[image]

This one works as `b` is not used anywhere (not being assigned some value).
However, now assume that `b` is assigned somewhere then the function below is evalued with that `b`.

[image]

And in the result below with replacment the result is `4` instead of `2` as what I want.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to subvert a pretty fundamental part of the language. Try to describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the solution you are attempting to implement. I suspect there might be another way to achieve your original goal.

Comment: One workaround would be to use Clear[b] just before you call myfunction. Or to add Clear[b] into the function: myfunction[a_] := Module[{}, Clear[b]; 1 + (2 a - 1) b].

Comment: @MarcoB I want to have a function that retun an expression with variables that I can replace  later to get the value if needed. If I make `b` local then I cannot return `b` but something like `$1000` and it's hard to replace for value later. 
ut

Comment: @bills I did that too but I wondered if there is  a better way as I used too many variables so I'm kind of lacking names.

Answer (score 4):

Why not define your function with two input variables?

myfunction[a_, b_] := Module[{},
1 + (2 a - 1) b ]

That way you can assignments like,
[image]

Although it's a bit more complex if you want a two-variable function to assign one variable with the second deferred you could also use the CurryApplied function.  This is a common feature in functional programming languages like Haskell.  So you can define:

```
myFunctionB = CurryApplied[myFunction, 2][x];
```

which will assign x to the variable a in myFunction.  And then at a later time, you can assign the variable b to myFunctionB:

```
myFunctionB[y]
```

which will return

```
1 + (-1 + 2 x) y
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is acceptable for you to return b in the function as a string instead of as a variable you could do the following:

```
f[a_]:=Module[{},  1 + (2 a - 1) "b" ]
```

Then you could just replace "b" instead of b:

```
f[1]/."b"->2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you could do:

```
myfunction[a_] := Block[{b},  HoldForm[Evaluate[1 + (2 a - 1) b]]]

b = 2;
ReleaseHold[myfunction[1] /. Unevaluated[b -> 1]]
```

I don't recommend this style of programming, though. It's easy to mess up the holding/releasing of evaluations and get a wrong result. If you need variables that are supposed to not have values assigned to them, I recommend using Formal symbols instead, such as:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalB.html

## Edit

Another strategy for the last line would be:

```
Block[{b = 1}, ReleaseHold[myfunction[1]]]
```